# How do I get my image upload to work on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, upload, server

I have a form that currently saves an image title, description and URL that uploads onto my project. I added an upload option to the form and now I'm confused as to how exactly it can save onto my server and show up after upload. Also - and this isn't priority - Is there also a way to assign my upload a url so users can share?

My form: (f.file_field picture is what I'm using to upload the image)

```
<h1>Add a picture</h1>
<%= link_to "Back to Pictures", pictures_url %>
<%= form_for @picture do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :artist %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :artist %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
    <p>
   <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  </p>
<% end %>

</center>
```

Controller:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end

  def new
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def create
    # make a new picture with what picture_params returns (which is a method we're calling)
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      # if the save for the picture was successful, go to index.html.erb
      redirect_to pictures_url
    else
      # otherwise render the view associated with the action :new (i.e. new.html.erb)
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
      redirect_to "/pictures/#{@picture.id}"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    redirect_to pictures_url
  end

  private
  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:artist, :title, :url)
  end

end
```

Thanks for your help! I want to keep this as minimal as possible and don't want to opt for a gem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `:picture` isn't ***permitted*** in your `picture_params`. Permit it to get saved in the ***DB***

```
def picture_params
   params.require(:picture).permit(:artist, :title, :url, :picture)
end
```

Comment: @icecreamrabbit You mean in the migration?

Comment: yeah, I assume when you say DB you mean my schema right?

Comment: Not really. I mean Databse. However you also need to add in the schema as well and the datatype could be `blob`

Comment: sorry, it's not working, can you quickly walk me thru both steps? the migration isn't working properly and I'm not sure what you mean by database. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try paper clip gem. this tutorial is also helpful.
https://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-paperclip